# tcp clients server communication

Tags: node.js, tcp

im trying to build TCP server/client chat
my code so far is

server.js

```
var net=require("net");
var sockets=[];
var server=net.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log("new socket connected");
    sockets.push(socket);
    var sh="";
    socket.on("data",function(data){
        sh=sh+data;
    });
    socket.on("end",function(){
        sockets.forEach(function(x){
            if(x!==socket){
                x.write("Dakto poveda :"+ sh);
                sh="";
            }
        });
    })
    socket.on("close",function(){
        console.log("Connection closed")
    })
}).listen(8888)
```

and client.js

```
var net=require("net");
var client= new net.Socket();
client.connect(8888,function(){
    console.log("Conncted");
    client.write("Hello from client")
});
client.on("data",function(data){
    console.log("data "+data)
});
client.on("close",function(){
    console.log("Client closed");
    client.write("client closed")
})
```

i start server.js then i open new cmds and start client.js in them . In the server cmd in writes that client has connected , and in the client cmd it writes "connected" and it doesnt write "hello from client" + the question is , how do i communicate between those clients / server? When i start those files , i cant write to cmd anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your server code waits until the client disconnects before displaying the buffered data to stdout. If you want to display it immediately, you will need to use some sort of framing protocol so you know when a "message" starts and ends. One popular method of doing that is to use newline-delimited JSON messages. For example:

`server.js`:

```
var net = require('net');
var sockets = [];
function broadcast(from, msg) {
  msg = JSON.stringify('Dakto poveda: ' + msg) + '\n';
  sockets.forEach(function(x) {
    if (x !== from)
      x.write(msg);
  });
}
var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
  sockets.push(socket);

  var buffer = '';
  socket.on('data',function(data) {
    buffer += data;
    var idx;
    while ((idx = buffer.indexOf('\n')) > -1) {
      broadcast(socket, JSON.parse(buffer.slice(0, idx)));
      buffer = buffer.slice(idx + 1);
    }
  });

  socket.on('close',function() {
    // Remove dead socket from list
    sockets.splice(sockets.indexOf(socket), 1);

    console.log('Connection closed')
  });
}).listen(8888);
```

`client.js`:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
function send(msg) {
  client.write(JSON.stringify(msg) + '\n');
}
client.connect(8888, function() {
  console.log('Conncted');
  send('Hello from client');
});
var buffer = '';
client.on('data', function(data) {
  buffer += data;
  var idx;
  while ((idx = buffer.indexOf('\n')) > -1) {
    console.log('message received: ' + JSON.parse(buffer.slice(0, idx)));
    buffer = buffer.slice(idx + 1);
  }
});
client.on('close',function(){
  console.log('Client closed');
});
```

The JSON conversion can be useful if you want to embed newlines and such in your messages, which would otherwise mess up your message framing. Another benefit is that you could send JavaScript objects, arrays, etc. instead of just plain strings. This would allow you to pass different kinds of data easier.

Comment: this really helped , but for the last question , why come i cannot write in the cmd after i have started cliend? without it im limited to static messages (ofc i could send some data from from end to it , but im just starting with node so i will try that later on)

Comment: @trolkura There is no single answer to that question. It all depends on the application. For example, if you're just making this a console-based thing that works in the terminal, then you would just read from stdin and send the message when the user presses enter. Or maybe you have your commands/input come from a redis pubsub channel. It just all depends.